# Proportional stacked bar graph, calculating percentage within stack for factors in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I've got a data frame (Df1) with two variables of the factor class, Site and Car. I'd like a proportional stacked bar graph that shows per site what percentage of all cars are old and what percentage are new. I'd like the graph to be proportional to make for easy comparisons between sites.

I'd like a graph that looks a lot like the output below, but I'd like the yaxis=Site, the xaxis=the sum of all cars (100%), and fill=Car.

Starting point (df):

```
Df1 <- data.frame(Site=c("GA","CA","NY","CA","NY","CA"),Car=c("new","new","new","old","old","new"))
```

Desired output:

```
library(gcookbook)
library(plyr)
ce = ddply(cabbage_exp, "Date", mutate, percent_weight = Weight/sum(Weight) * 100)
ggplot(ce, aes(x=Date, y=percent_weight, fill=Cultivar)) + 
geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

My attempt:

```
library(plyr)
Df2 <- ddply(Df1,"Site",transform,
PercentCar = count(Car)/sum(count(Car))*100)
ggplot <- (Df2, aes(x=PercentCar, y=Site,fill=Car))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R solution.

```
## Some test data
Site = sample(1:3, 20, replace=TRUE)
Car  = sample(c("Old", "New"), 20, replace=TRUE)

T1 = table(Site, Car)
Prop1 = T1/rowSums(T1)
barplot(t(Prop1), horiz=TRUE, col=rainbow(2))
```

[image: Proportional barplots]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using dplyr group_by rather than plyr to wrangle the data.

```
library(dplyr)
Df1 <- data.frame(Site=c("GA","CA","NY","CA","NY","CA"),
                  Car=c("new","new","new","old","old","new"))
Df2 <- Df1 %>%
    group_by(Site, Car) %>%
    count() %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(prop = n/sum(n))

ggplot(Df2, aes(x = Site, y = prop, fill = Car)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    coord_flip()
```

So what's going on: I group by both Site and Car so that both variables stay in the data, and so that the count() function distinguishes between old cars from CA and new cars from CA. Then I ungroup so that when I create the new prop column in mutate(), the 'sum(n)' bit sums the entire column, rather than only summing the n column within each group.

[image]

Comment: Adrian Martin: I get Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object 'freq' not found. I'm guessing prop = n / sum(n). But Car doesn't appear to be in Df2, or am mistaken? count(Car)? Get something slightly different from the graph above.

Comment: You're right, let me fix the code. Not sure why that code worked before.